# delete "sum of" from histogram px.df

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color='day', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

well, i have a function like that

And it builds a histogram in plotly dash

but it makes with lable "sum of total_bill", but i need just "total_bill", how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the `yaxis_title` as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="day", y="total_bill", category_orders=dict(day=["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]))
fig.update_layout( yaxis_title="total_bill" )
fig.show()
```

[image]